# Can't able to style properly in Angular16

Tags: css, angular, typescript

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <app-cards *ngFor=" let card of cards; index as i; 
                        first as isFirst; last as isLast; odd as isOdd; even as isEven" 
        [cardIndex]="i+1" (outputValue)="onCardSelected($event)" [inputValue]="card" 
        [class.isFirst]="isFirst" [class.isEnd]="isLast" [class.isOdd]="isOdd" [class.isEven]="isEven">
    </app-cards>
</div>
```

cards.component.html

```
<div>
    <h1>{{index + '. ' + webSeries.name}}</h1>
    <img [src]="webSeries.image" />
    <button (click)="onWebSeriesView()">Watch Series</button>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```
app-cards.isFirst{
    border: 1rem solid black;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Output is :-

[image]

CSS Border & Padding is not applied properly. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By defect a component has `display:inline`. So you need take acount about this. generally you can simply add, e.g.`display:block` or `display:inline-block`.

```
  my-card.isFirst{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:block;
    background:yellow;
  }
  //or simply
  .isFirst{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:block;
    background:yellow;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `isFirst` boolean is true then just having the CSS selector should work:

```
.isFirst {
    border: 1rem solid black;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

You may need to consider adding `!important` to styles to override defaults.

```
.isFirst {
    border: 1rem solid black !important;
    padding: 1rem !important;
}
```

If you want to target add space before the selector:

```
app-cards .isFirst {
    border: 1rem solid black;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

> The descendant combinator — typically represented by a single space (" ") character — combines two selectors such that elements matched by the second selector are selected if they have an ancestor (parent, parent's parent, parent's parent's parent, etc.) element matching the first selector. Selectors that utilize a descendant combinator are called descendant selectors.

Read more about descendant selector here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator